# trouble with image grid in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to make a grid of images that I have made into circle images using img-circle. I want 3 columns and 3 rows of images in a grid formation which I've written using bootstrap:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img1.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img2.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img3.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img4.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img5.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img6.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img7.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img8.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"> <img src="img9.png" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

however when I check what it looks like, it results in the images lining up vertically. So the images are converted to circle images, but go down in a line rather than a grid formation. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or if I'm supposed to be doing something in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's `col-md-*` has a breakpoint for responsiveness. If your device is less then that or you resize your browser to less then that, you'll see your images above each other. So, if you do not want your grid to break, you `col-xm-*` instead of `col-md-*`. Look at the snippet-

```css
.img-circle{
  display:block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"> <img src="https://www.topnotchlearning.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/nature1.jpg" class="img-circle"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ok so i realized my problem was bootstrap wasn't connected to my html, because once I added the link, it worked. If I downloaded bootstrap, how am I supposed to connect it to my html page? I put the bootstrap zip file into the folder with my html/css code but not sure how to link it otherwise.

Comment: uncompress the zip file and then connect the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js the same way you connect external css and js files.